# Spring Security REST Login

Tags: spring, rest, api, security, authentication

I got question about login with REST API with Spring Security. As far as login with default login window provided by Spring Security is working and it is authenticating with Database, I have no idea how to make my own login. I know how to substitute the form for my own, but where should I send the data? Should I POST it for some address? I made basic form with username and password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one, it might help you... at least to understand what you are missing.
This code is not guarantee to be worked 100%, some part is intentionally missed (error handling and it's format, loading user, some checks, Session API).

The basic idea is you must to register a filter (react on all secured request for authentication process) and a provider that later on will be able to load authonticated user and create for you security context (e.g. you know each request is handled per thread and this user can be obtained by SecurityContextHolder/ThreadLocal).

And you need to create a separate controller to handle the initial case for creating a user session aka login/Authorization. Response of this API must to contain some session's GUID to use it as value of header later on: `Authentication: Bearer <value>`

some spec: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)//optional
@Import(RestSecurityConfig.TokenAuthenticationProvider.class)// one of the way to create spring bean
public class RestSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private static final RequestMatcher PUBLIC_URLS = new OrRequestMatcher(
            new AntPathRequestMatcher("/actuator/*"),
            new AntPathRequestMatcher("/some_api_to_login", POST), // this must be public
    );
    private static final RequestMatcher PROTECTED_URLS = new NegatedRequestMatcher(PUBLIC_URLS);

    // better to move it out as a separate class
    public static class TokenAuthenticationProvider extends AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider {
        @Override
        public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
            return MyAuthenticationToken.class.isAssignableFrom(authentication);
        }

        @Override
        protected void additionalAuthenticationChecks(UserDetails userDetails, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication) throws AuthenticationException {

        }

        @Override
        protected UserDetails retrieveUser(String username, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
            return null; // service/dao.loadUser
        }
    }

    public static class TokenAuthenticationFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {
        public TokenAuthenticationFilter(RequestMatcher requiresAuthenticationRequestMatcher) {
            super(requiresAuthenticationRequestMatcher);
        }

        @Override
        public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException {
            Authentication auth = new MyAuthenticationToken(request.getHeader("Authentication"));
            return getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(auth);
        }
    }

    @Autowired
    TokenAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

    @Override
    protected void configure(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(final WebSecurity web) {
        web.ignoring().requestMatchers(PUBLIC_URLS);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // maybe some of the tuning you might not need
        http
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor(new Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint(), PROTECTED_URLS).and()
                .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and()
                .cors().and()
                .anonymous().disable()
                .rememberMe().disable()
                .csrf().disable()
                .formLogin().disable()
                .httpBasic().disable()
                .logout().disable();

        // it's important
        http.addFilterBefore(tokenAuthenticationFilter(), AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    @Bean
    AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter tokenAuthenticationFilter() throws Exception {
        final AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter filter = new TokenAuthenticationFilter(PROTECTED_URLS);
        filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
        filter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(successHandler());
        // maybe error handling to provide some custom response?
        return filter;
    }

    // it's critically important to register your filter properly in spring context
    /** Disable Spring boot automatic filter registration. */
    @Bean
    FilterRegistrationBean disableRegistrationForAuthenticationFilter(final TokenAuthenticationFilter filter) {
        final FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean(filter);
        registration.setEnabled(false);
        return registration;
    }

    // this one also is critically important to avoid redirection
    @Bean
    SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler() {
        final SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler = new SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
        successHandler.setRedirectStrategy(new NoRedirectStrategy());
        return successHandler;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store usernames and passwords in database, which you can use to login users. You create your own class which extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter and override methods which you need to modify:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception{
        auth.jdbcAuthentication()
            .dataSource(dataSource)
    }
}
```

But be vary of Spring Security default database query when searching for usernames and passwords so you can create database schema which will be good:

```
public static final String DEF_USERS_BY_USERNAME_QUERY =
"select username,password,enabled " +
"from users " +
"where username = ?";
public static final String DEF_AUTHORITIES_BY_USERNAME_QUERY =
"select username,authority " +
"from authorities " +
"where username = ?";
public static final String DEF_GROUP_AUTHORITIES_BY_USERNAME_QUERY =
"select g.id, g.group_name, ga.authority " +
"from groups g, group_members gm, group_authorities ga " +
"where gm.username = ? " +
"and g.id = ga.group_id " +
"and g.id = gm.group_id";
```

But you can also use Spring methods to specify your own query to database:

```
auth
.jdbcAuthentication()
.dataSource(dataSource)
.usersByUsernameQuery(
"select username, password, enabled from Users " +
"where username=?")
```

You should POST your data to some service you created which will store user and pass to a database.

Comment: I got it and its working, but the problem is how can I log to the user? I tried to send JSON to the "/login" with username and password but still it was redirecting me to the login page ( no error/ nothing)

Comment: If you are using Spring Security Login configuration you don't need to, except to store it properly.

Comment: I mean I want to change the form for my own, I know that how to do it but I dont know what kind of JSON should I sent to the "/login" to authenticate the user.

Comment: In Spring Security configuration file define your custom login form as instructed here https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/guides/html5/form-javaconfig.html

Comment: Please don't store passwords in the database (or anywhere else): Only ever store cryptographic hashes